# Simple Syntax: Multiple Constraints in Alter Table Statement

Tags: sql-server-2008

If I have this statement:

```
ALTER TABLE RecipeBox.Recipe ADD CONSTRAINT AKRecipeBox_Recipe_Name 
UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED (Name)
```

How do I add another constraint to this statement? Is this even possible?

Thanks

Using SQL SERVER 2008 Developer Edition

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add a comma, then add the new constraint (without add keyword) like this:

```
ALTER TABLE RecipeBox.Recipe ADD CONSTRAINT AKRecipeBox_Recipe_Name 
UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED (Name), 
CONSTRAINT your_constraint UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED (yourColumn) -- (or whatever type of constraint you're looking for)
```

Answer (score 7):

Change the layout slightly and read [ALTER TABLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx)

```
ALTER TABLE RecipeBox.Recipe WITH CHECK ADD
    CONSTRAINT AKRecipeBox_Recipe_Name UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED (Name),
    CONSTRAINT FK_foo_bar FOREIGN KEY ..., 
    CONSTRAINT CK_foo_bar CHECK (...)
```

Edit: use WITH CHECK to ensure the constraints are valid...

Answer (score 4):

Since the title of this question does not refer to SQL Server, I opened it to find a solution for Oracle DB which is different from accepted answer. So I will leave it below in case someone else follows my steps.

For Oracle DB:

```
ALTER TABLE RecipeBox.Recipe
ADD (CONSTRAINT your_first_constraint, CONSTRAINT your_second_constraint);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE RecipeBox,Recipe WITH CHECK 
ADD   CONSTRAINT Cons_1 UNIQUE CLUSTERED
(
    Col1,
    Col2
)
```

In case of a check constraint you can also use a rule