# Add multiple constraints in one statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, constraints

I am supposed to modify my current table named MEMBER in Microsoft SQL Server 2012.

I am trying to modify the tables

```
ALTER TABLE MEMBER
ADD CONSTRAINT U_MEMBERID UNIQUE(MEMBER_ID), primary key (MEMBER_ID);
ADD CONSTRAINT Sys_date DEFAULT GETDATE() FOR MEMBER_ID;
```

The above doesn't work and it says:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CONSTRAINT'.

I think I am doing something wrong, but I am not sure what it is.

```
ALTER TABLE TITLE 
ADD CONSTRAINT U_TITLEID UNIQUE(TITLE_ID), primary key (TITLE_ID);
add constraint C_CATEGORY CHECK(CATEGORY='DRAMA' OR 'COMEDY' OR 'ACTION'
OR 'CHILD' OR 'SCIFI' OR 'DOCUMENTARY';
```

Also: is it possible to add the above code to the code preceding it and execute both of them in the same sql query?

How do I fix this?

Comment: The last bit is probably a question on its own ("Is it possible to execute two DDL statements on different tables in one sql query?").

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You have three problems:

1. You terminate the statement with the `;` at the end of your second line of code.
2. You have `FOR MEMBER_ID` in the last statement, which should probably be `FOR Sys_date`.
3. You repeat `ADD` but [don't have to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4772566/419956).

Assuming this table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE Member (MEMBER_ID BIGINT NOT NULL, Sys_date DATETIME);
```

This DDL will work:

```
ALTER TABLE MEMBER
ADD CONSTRAINT U_MEMBERID UNIQUE(MEMBER_ID), primary key (MEMBER_ID),
    CONSTRAINT Sys_date DEFAULT GETDATE() FOR Sys_date;
```

See [this sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1b90d/14).

You *can* theoretically also see this on the [MSDN's page on `ALTER TABLE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx), though I'd readily admit those specs can be hard to read. Here's a stab at how they explain it:

```
ALTER TABLE [ database_name . [ schema_name ] . | schema_name . ] table_name 
{ 
    ALTER COLUMN column_name 
    -- Omitted....
    | ADD 
    { 
        <column_definition>
      | <computed_column_definition>
      | <table_constraint> 
      | <column_set_definition> 
    } [ ,...n ]
    -- Omitted....
```

The `ADD` keyword occurs once, and the `} [ ,...n ]` bit tells you that you can repeat the bit between {brackets} `n` times, separated by a `,`.

Answer (score -7):

```
ALTER TABLE MEMBER ADD CONSTRAINT U_MEMBERID UNIQUE(MEMBER_ID), primary key (MEMBER_ID);
ALTER TABLE MEMBER ADD CONSTRAINT Sys_date DEFAULT GETDATE() FOR MEMBER_ID;
```