# Issue with MySQL, cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a table named appointment, though when I try to create it I receive the error:

> Cannot add foreign key constraint

My SQL code is as follows:

```
 CREATE TABLE APPOINTMENT(
    APNo VARCHAR(5),
    PNo VARCHAR(5), 
    DNo VARCHAR(5),
    APDATE DATETIME
);

ALTER TABLE APPOINTMENT
    ADD PRIMARY KEY (APNo),
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (PNo) REFERENCES PATIENT(PNo),
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (DNo) REFERENCES DOCTOR(DNo)
;
```

Comment: You have to use multiple ALTER TABLE statements

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add multiple constraints in one statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24593101/add-multiple-constraints-in-one-statement)

Comment: Please show us the DDL for tables `PATIENT` and `DOCTOR`.

Answer (score 0):

You syntax looks ok. You are not showing the DDL for referrenced tables `PATIENT` and `DOCTOR`, however it is likely that the error happens because one of MySQL foreign keys requirements is not met.

Quotes from [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html):

> Corresponding columns in the foreign key and the referenced key must have similar data types.

You must ensure that both `DOCTOR(DNo)` and `PATIENT(PNo)` are `VARCHAR(5)`.

> MySQL requires indexes on foreign keys and referenced keys. [...] Such an index is created on the referencing table automatically if it does not exist.

Ideally, `DOCTOR(DNo)` and `PATIENT(PNo)` should be the primary key of their respective tables. Else, an index must exist for each of them (it could be a multi-column index where the referrenced column appears once).

---

See [this db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cEQi7nxCTKkj5aQwSaeEp7/1) for a working example:

```
CREATE TABLE PATIENT(PNo VARCHAR(5) PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE TABLE DOCTOR(DNo VARCHAR(5) PRIMARY KEY);

CREATE TABLE APPOINTMENT(
    APNo VARCHAR(5),
    PNo VARCHAR(5), 
    DNo VARCHAR(5),
    APDATE DATETIME
);

ALTER TABLE APPOINTMENT
    ADD PRIMARY KEY (APNo),
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (PNo) REFERENCES PATIENT(PNo),
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (DNo) REFERENCES DOCTOR(DNo)
;
```